# Google Chrome Browser under Mac and Windows environment for input type=range

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

I am using HTML 5 attribute input type="range" and i need - and + symbols before and after the attribute.

I am not able to align it properly. In MAC if i set the css styling, it doesnt fit to windows. Browser remains the same. Google Chrome.  Here is the jsfiddle.

I am keeping the html and not sharing the css as its not confined to any set of code.

```
   <label>-</label>
   <input type="range" name="points" class="rangeClass" min="0" max="10">
  <label>+</label>
```

Let me explain the problem again. I am using Google Chrome Browser under Mac and Windows environment. The css styling doesnt fit to both. Still not tested with firefox.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/xo5fsd5s/). Updated with css styling for input range.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pseudo classes instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/xo5fsd5s/2/

```
<input type="range" name="points" class="input input--range" min="0" max="10">


.input {
    position: relative;
}

.input--range {

    &:before,
    &:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 10px;
        height: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        content: '-';
    }

    &:before {
        left: -15px;
        content: '-';
    }

    &:after {
        right: -15px;
        content: '+';
    }
```

Comment: tried it. Not fixing the issue. Will the resolution plays the role here? Just a doubt.

Comment: Hi..Good day. I have updated my JSFIDDLE with css styling. Now you can see the - and + have changed its location.